# How to get an object in memory ? python pointers

Tags: python, pointers, memory, garbage-collection

I don't know if this is possible but I'm trying to open an object from another script by i'ts place on the memory

This is my first script:

```
from time import sleep
myobj = 'Hi'

# i'm aware that this somehow is the position of the object on memory
myid = id(myobj)

print(myid)
# output: 140196737647120

sleep(3600)
```

how i could try to open it from a non related script?
I tried with:

```
from ctypes import cast, py_object
jc = cast( 140196737647120 , py_object).value
# output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also if there is some other easier way please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual memory renders this impossible without altering Python to use **shared memory** (which is a lot harder to do safely than it sounds).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did not solve the question but the information was good, at the end i found this https://gitlab.com/tenzing/shared-array , Thank you.

Comment: @VasylYovdiy: It did answer the *question*, which to your credit acknowledged that the answer might be “you can’t”.  I’m glad you found a library you could use; `multiprocessing` in the standard library also supports (some) such use cases.